# Curl POST attachment

Tags: php, curl, http-post, ringcentral

I need to attach a pdf file form local drive and post it to the API using PHP CURL.

Here is the [RingCentral FaxOut API Documentation](https://service.ringcentral.com/faxoutapi/)

```
$url = "https://service.ringcentral.com/faxapi.asp";

$data = array(

    'Username' => 'XXXXXXXXX', 
    'Password' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'Recipient' => 'XXXXXXXXXX|Navneet',
    'Coverpage' => 'Default',
    'Coverpagetext' => 'Testing Faxout API ',
    'Resolution' => 'High',
    "Sendtime"   => date('d:m:y H:i:s'),
    'Attachment' => file_get_contents(PATH_TO_FILE)

);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

API do not return anything in response. I think, I'm not sending the attachment properly. The attachment should be in binary stream. I tried base64_encode but no success.

As given in the Request body example, header for attachment should be like this

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Attachment"; filename="C:\example.doc" 
<Document content is here>
-----------------------------7d54b1fee05aa
```

Comment: It was better you specify your code and you error
"API dont accept it , is not a good explanation bro"

Comment: You are using the old API. Try out the new [RingCentral API](https://developers.ringcentral.com/) and [PHP SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-php) for which there is more support.

Answer (score 0):

You can POST anything to the api with CURL, `$doc` in my example is anything you want to post , it can be a json_encoded file , a base64_encoded image or pdf or anything else.

```
$baseUri = https://service.ringcentral.com/faxapi.asp;

$doc = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_FILE);

$ci = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUri);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $doc);

// also you can specify any specific header like this : 

$h1['Content-Disposition'] =  'Content-Disposition'. ': ' . 'form-data'; // headers are key-value pairs right ? 

curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_values($h1));  // you can use this line for each header as a new key-value pair 

$h2['name'] =  'name'. ': ' . 'Attachment'; 
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_values($h2));
$h3['filename'] =  'filename'. ': ' . 'C:\example.doc'; 
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_values($h3));

$response = curl_exec($ci);
```

**NOTE ** : its a good Idea to first of all check to see if your file_get_contents function works : 
so in another php file check to see this :

```
echo file_get_contents(PATH_TO_FILE);
```

See if it echoes correctly

Comment: You should probably use a `CURLFile` instead of creating your own object.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the function and how I generated the info for the request

```
function send_curl_request_with_attachment($method, $headers, $url, $post_fields) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
if($headers != "" && count($headers) > 0){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  
return $result;}

$token_slams = "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token;
$authHeader = array(
$token_slams,
'Accept: application/form-data');

$schedule_path ='../../documents/' . $docs_record["document"];
$cFile = curl_file_create($schedule_path);

$post = array(
    'old_record' => $old_record,
    'employer_number' => $employer_number,
    'payment_date' => $payment_date,
    'fund_year' => $fund_year,
    'fund_month' => $fund_month,
    'employer_schedule'=> $cFile
);

send_curl_request_with_attachment("POST", $authHeader, $my_url, $post);
```